# Same notifications is repeated with user after each exit from application

Tags: android

I use Service in my app to send Notifications to user after the user exits the application; it's work but I have one problem after user exits from app every time he gets last notification received each time he enters and leaves, the same notice is repeated even if there is no new notice. This is problem. Notifications should only be sent from once time to user, and if he exit next time it should not be sent again. Just if he have a new notification with a new ID it must be sent once time to user.

This is class my service

```
public class MyService extends Service {





    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start myServis", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //    run_loop();
        return START_STICKY;
    }




    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stopmyservci", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

I get data by this code ..

```
 public void run_loop(){
        String url =  "http://00000000/testnet/android_register_login/ShowAllData.php";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                String id = hit.getString("id");
                                int lastThread = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id));
                                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivtiy.this, lastThread + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if (app.getTotal_threads() < lastThread) {
                                    app.setTotal_threads(lastThread);
                                    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivtiy.this)
                                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
                                            .setContentTitle("title")
                                            .setContentText("message")
                                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                                            .build();

                                    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

                            }
                            } catch(JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);


        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                run_loop();
            }
        },10000);

    }
```

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent sr =new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(sr);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        run_loop();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

I store id here

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";
    private int Total_threads;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannels();
    }
    public int getTotal_threads() {
        return Total_threads;
    }
    public void setTotal_threads(int Total_threads) {
        this.Total_threads = Total_threads;
    }
    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_2_ID, "Channel 2", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );
            channel2.setDescription("This is Channel 2");

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
}
```

and I get it from here

```
    private void JSON() {
        String url = "http://00000000/test/Showall.php";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                                String id= hit.getString("id");




app.setTotal_threads(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));

                            }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: where do you store the `app` value, and when do you restore it?

Comment: I stor it in global class and I get It from mainactivity

Comment: I get it from same class when I make code of get notification

Comment: is it a shared preference value ?

Comment: If the value is not persistently stored in persistent storage like in shared preference, then it could be lost from some reason like configuration changes.. I mean it's more reliably to be stored as a shared prefs value ... your issue is mainly that the condition `if (app.getTotal_threads() < lastThread)` is met twice

Comment: I get it like that ===app.setTotal_threads(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));==and I store it in==public class App extends Application ===as  public int getTotal_threads() {
        return Total_threads;
    }
    public void setTotal_threads(int Total_threads) {
        this.Total_threads = Total_threads;
    }

Comment: but it's not shared preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons in my mind for that:

The first is that your condition `if (app.getTotal_threads() < lastThread)` is met twice because the value of the `Total_threads` is lost for some reason, so you need to persistently store it like using a shared preference. Here is a modification for the `App` class to do that.

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PREFS_NAME";
    public static final String N_THREADS = "nThreads";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannels();
    }

    public int getTotal_threads() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt(N_THREADS, 0);
    }

    public void setTotal_threads(int Total_threads) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(N_THREADS, Total_threads);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_2_ID, "Channel 2", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );
            channel2.setDescription("This is Channel 2");

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
}
```

The other possible reason is that the server could send the same notification with different thread number .. in this case you've to fix the back end.

Comment: Same problem brother //how I can do that ( in this case you've to fix the back end.)?

Comment: It is running in the first second of closing the application, it appears as if it was linked to closing the application

Comment: @marwan why you call `run_loop();` in the `onBackPressed` while that should be done in the service class ?

Comment: Because I use run_loop (); at main activity

Comment: Your answer was correct, but due to a different problem in the application it did not work and now it works .. Thank you brother and I apologize for that a little experience I'm a new developer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're using the `Handler` to call `run_loop()` inside your `run_loop()` function. It might be producing a loop that makes you receive multiple notifications. Try moving it outside of the loop and check if it works.